# How to assign properties dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a function that has two parameters:

1. The name of the tag that I want to create
2. An object that has the properties

Using **React**, I create a component and render that element to DOM. The problem is that I want to add properties to the element, but it does not allow the loop to set properties within element.

```js
var Element = function(element, properties) {
  var newElement = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        React.createElement(element, {}, 'react reuseable')
      );
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(newElement, null), document.getElementById('content'));
}
```

Here is the function call to create a React element:

```js
Element('g', {
  id: 'DrawingController.drawingPathCounter ' + '_shape',
  d: 'path',
  fill: 'none',
  stroke: 'Controllers.TemplateController.wireFrameColour_Selected',
  'stroke-width': 1,
  'class': 'drawingpath',
  pathhover: '',
  'vector-effect': 'non-scaling-stroke'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-implementing the existing `React.createElement` method.

You can just store the unique props for your components in an array, then create a list of components using those props.

```
var propsList = [
  { id: 1, d: 'path', fill: 'none' }, 
  { id: 2, d: 'path', fill: 'none' }, 
  { id: 3, d: 'path', fill: 'none' } 
];

var components = propsList.map(function(props) {
  return React.createElement('g', props);
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, components);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

If you want the properties list to be dynamic, then you should store it inside your component's state.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      propsList: []
    };
  },
  addProps: function(props) {
    var propsList = this.state.propsList.concat([props]);
    this.setState({ propsList: propsList });
  },
  render: function() {
    var components = this.state.propsList.map(function(props) {
      return React.createElement('g', props);
    });

    return React.createElement('div', null, components);
  }
});
```

Comment: i want to make different component with different properties so i this is not satisfies my need i want some modification

Comment: The second argument to `React.createElement` is a properties object, just pass a different properties object in each time you want to make a component with different properties.

Comment: will you please do a favor by guide me how i do in this case

Comment: this is the code duplication method we are writing the same code again and again just changing the props and this eleminate the concept of modularity. we want to make code modular

Comment: But that is the minimum amount of code that it's possible to write. To instantiate a component, the essential bits of data are the name of the component and the props it takes. This is the form that JSX compiles to.

Comment: i need to create more then 50 g tags while working with svg so for 50 g tags will i have to write the code for each? if not how to incorporate that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96468/discussion-between-no-speaking-guy-and-dan-prince).